Как найти значение элемента таблицы CSV в pandas?
Создадим файл data.csv и запишем туда:
name,age
John,20
Paul,25
Kate,23

Я хочу вывести на экран возраст John (age - это возраст). Как мне это сделать?

print(df.loc[df['name'] == 'John', 'age'])

Чтобы найти и вывести на экран возраст John в pandas, вам сначала нужно загрузить данные из файла CSV в DataFrame, а затем использовать индексацию и условную фильтрацию для извлечения необходимого значения.
import pandas as pd

# Загружаем данные в DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Фильтруем DataFrame для поиска строки с именем John и извлекаем его возраст

age_of_john = data.loc[data['name'] == 'John', 'age'].values[0]
# или другой вариант
#age_of_john = data[data['name'] == 'John']['age'].iloc[0]

# Выводим возраст John на экран
print(f"Возраст John: {age_of_john}")


Многоэтажную индексацию data[data['name'] == 'John']['age'] лучше не использовать, используйте лучше .loc как у меня в примере.

age_of_john = data.loc[data['name'] == 'John', 'age'].values[0]

Ну да, только вы можете редактировать ответ, если что.
